# higher order differential equation with two functions dependent on x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know if the following differential equation is solvable and what kind of steps I need to take or where to look to learn the steps. Sadly i do not know enough about differential equations to solve it.

I think i do not want to write it al out by hand a solver(function?) with Matlab would be sufficient. But i do not know if a solution is possible at all.

$$ \frac{d^4  v}{d x^4} = -c(x)v(x) $$

Where $ c(x) $ is for instance:
$$ c(x) = 3x$$

With boundary conditions:
$$ v'''(0) = -F$$
$$ v'(0)= 0$$

$$ v'''(L) = F$$
$$ v'(L)= 0$$

Comment: This is in general a tough problem, since you have a prescribed boundary and your Equation is of fourth order. An overview of the general theory of these kind of equations can be found in http://www-ian.math.uni-magdeburg.de/home/grunau/papers/book_GGS.pdf chapter 2. Be warned though, because this book treats partial differential equations and your problem is a simplified version.

Comment: If you are just looking for a solution, software can help, with Wolfram Alpha ,for example, giving you a generic solution of your equation (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5BD%5Bv%5Bx%5D,+%7Bx,+4%7D%5D+%3D%3D+3*x*v%5Bx%5D,+v%5Bx%5D,+x%5D), in terms of hypergeometric functions, that you can adapt to your boundary conditions. However you can notice that the result is relatively complicated. Proving it from scratch would be quite long.

Comment: Based on the book mentioned by @humanStampedist I am starting to think that i put myself into too deep waters. I am just looking for a solution so i adapted my question a bit. I am trying in wolfram alpha at the moment as you mentioned